# flickr.photos.licenses.getInfoにパブリックドメインは含まれない？

Tags: api, flickr

**やりたいこと**
・フリッカーで、(APIを通じて、)パブリックドメインやCC0の画像を取得したい

**質問**
・下記リンク先に、「パブリックドメインやCC0」が含まれていないのはなぜでしょうか？
・7の「No known copyright restrictions」が「パブリックドメインやCC0」を指すのでしょうか？
・それとも、「flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo」では取得できないので、別のAPIを使用するのでしょうか？

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PublicDomainやCC0はあとから追加されたのでドキュメントが更新されていないのだと思います。Flickr Api Explorerを使ったら最新のデータを取得できました。

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <licenses>
    <license id="0" name="All Rights Reserved" url="" />
    <license id="4" name="Attribution License" url="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/" />
    <license id="6" name="Attribution-NoDerivs License" url="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/" />
    <license id="3" name="Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs License" url="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/" />
    <license id="2" name="Attribution-NonCommercial License" url="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/" />
    <license id="1" name="Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike License" url="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/" />
    <license id="5" name="Attribution-ShareAlike License" url="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/" />
    <license id="7" name="No known copyright restrictions" url="https://www.flickr.com/commons/usage/" />
    <license id="8" name="United States Government Work" url="http://www.usa.gov/copyright.shtml" />
    <license id="9" name="Public Domain Dedication (CC0)" url="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/" />
    <license id="10" name="Public Domain Mark" url="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/" />
  </licenses>
</rsp>
```